# Using dplyr::left_join inside a custom function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I would like to create a function that merges two different tables, using two different columns from each data set.

```
df_1 <- data.frame(state_symbol = c('MG', 'SP', 'BA'),
                   city = c('Sao Paulo', 'Sao Paulo', 'Brumado'),
                   collected_data = c('red', 'green', 'blue'))

df_2 <- data.frame(S_Symb = c('MG', 'BA', "SP"),
                   municip = c('Sao Paulo', 'Brumado', 'Sao Paulo'),
                   population = c(123, 456, 789))

left_join(x = df_1,
          y = df_2,
          by = c("state_symbol" = "S_Symb",
                 "city" = "municip"))`
```

This produces the correct result:

```
  state_symbol      city collected_data population
1           MG Sao Paulo            red        123
2           SP Sao Paulo          green        789
3           BA   Brumado           blue        456
```

Now I want to use this code inside a function. I tried the following:

```
my_join <- function(tab_1,
                    tab_2,
                    df_1_city_col,
                    df_1_state_col,
                    df_2_city_col,
                    df_2_state_col) {
    
    output <- dplyr::left_join(x = tab_1,
                               y = tab_2,
                               by = c({{df_1_city_col}} = {{df_2_city_col}},
                                     {{df_1_state_col}} = {{df_2_state_col}}))
    return(output)
}
```

But that produced the following error:

```
> my_join <- function(tab_1,
+                     tab_2,
+                     df_1_city_col,
+                     df_1_state_col,
+                     df_2_city_col,
+                     df_2_state_col) {
+     
+     output <- dplyr::left_join(x = tab_1,
+                                y = tab_2,
+                                by = c({{df_1_city_col}} = {{df_2_city_col}},
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"                               y = tab_2,
                               by = c({{df_1_city_col}} ="
```

Apparently, functions don't deal well with the notation `c(something = something_else)`. The `=` inside that parenthesis is too much for it and it instantaneously produces an error no matter what I try.

Just for reference, my function call would look like this:

```
my_join(tab_1 = df_1,
        tab_2 = df_2,
        df_1_city_col = 'city',
        df_1_state_col = 'state_symbol',
        df_2_city_col = 'municip',
        df_2_state_col = 'S_Symb')
```

I saw some other similar answered questions, but couldn't find one where the join needs to occur between two columns from each input table.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `c("state_symbol" = "S_Symb","city" = "municip")` actually creates a named vector which you can create with `setNames` to use it inside a function.

```
my_join <- function(tab_1,
                    tab_2,
                    df_1_city_col,
                    df_1_state_col,
                    df_2_city_col,
                    df_2_state_col) {
  
  output <- dplyr::left_join(x = tab_1,
                             y = tab_2,
                             by = setNames(c(df_2_city_col, df_2_state_col),
                                            c(df_1_city_col, df_1_state_col)))
  return(output)
}

my_join(tab_1 = df_1,
        tab_2 = df_2,
        df_1_city_col = 'city',
        df_1_state_col = 'state_symbol',
        df_2_city_col = 'municip',
        df_2_state_col = 'S_Symb')

#  state_symbol      city collected_data population
#1           MG Sao Paulo            red        123
#2           SP Sao Paulo          green        789
#3           BA   Brumado           blue        456
```

---

In base R, you can use `by.x` and `by.y` to specify the columns to merge.

```
my_join <- function(tab_1,
                    tab_2,
                    df_1_city_col,
                    df_1_state_col,
                    df_2_city_col,
                    df_2_state_col) {
  
  output <- merge(tab_1, tab_2, 
                  by.x = c(df_1_city_col, df_1_state_col), 
                  by.y = c(df_2_city_col, df_2_state_col), 
                  all.x = TRUE)
  
  return(output)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not know that `c("state_symbol" = "S_Symb","city" = "municip")` was creating a named vector. Could you perhaps comment further on that? Also, It is good to know a base R solution.

Comment: If you print `c("state_symbol" = "S_Symb","city" = "municip")` in the console you'll see the structure of the named vector it creates. The goal is to create something similar with `setNames`.